# Promise.all([...]) filling in object

Tags: javascript, promise

I have an object with some ids that I need to replace with their associated objects by fetching at different endpoints.

```
{
  user: 123456
  items: [
    1234,
    4321,
  ]
}
```

and I want to fetch it where a is endpoint `GET /user` for the userId and `GET /item` for each of the item ids.  I want a full object to be returned like:

```
{
  user: { ... }
  items: [
    { ... } 
    { ... } 
  ]
}
```

All of my user and item functions work and are using async fetch so I think I want something along the lines o:

```
const fillIn = async data => {
  return Promise.all(
    data.map(async obj => {
      const userId = obj.userId;
      const itemIds = obj.items
      return Promise.all([
        getUser(creatorId),
        Promise.all(itemIds.map(item => getItem(item)))
      ]);
    })
  );
};
```

My question is what does promise.all return and when does it return it?  I keep getting functions back unresolved but I thought the whole point of it was to resolve all the promises!?

Comment: Please show the full code, including the `data` and the `getUser` / `getItem`

Comment: `Promise.all` returns a promise. From which you can call `.then()` and other promise methods on

Comment: If you're trying to make async code synchronous (which I think you are), it's not possible. You have to either `await` it or use `.then()`.

Comment: promise.all is just a promise that is resolved when all the promises are resolved from the promise array that you have entered. think of it as a promise wrapping other promises, also using the async await syntax means you have to use await on all of your async calls. like other people said here

Comment: I missed the question "and when does it return it?". The answer is immediately. `Promise.all()` **resolves** the promise it returns immediately after *every* promise listed in the array you pass into `Promise.all()` resolves, and it rejects immediately after *any* of the promises passed in rejects. You can handle these by using `Promise.all([...]).then(responses => {/* success/resolved */ }, err => { /* error/rejected */})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you need returns a promise that is fulfilled with the "filled in" the object.  That promise is really a composition of promises: one for the user, and an array for each item in items...

```
function fillIn(object) {
    let filledInObject = { user:null, items:[] };
    let promises = object.items.map(i => {
        return getItem(i).then(item => filledInObject.items.push(item));
    });
    let userPromise = getUser(object.user).then(user => {
        filledInObject.user = user;
    });
    promises.push(userPromise);
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

One can also imagine a more general solution where property names are mapped to getters in some config object:

```
// getUser and getItem are assumed as above
// add a plural form for getItems
// our getters will be indexed like this: { user:getUser, items:getItems }

function getItems(array) {
    let promises = array.map(i => getItem(i));
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Now, a general filler-inner...

```
function fillIn(object, getters) {
    let filledInObject = {};
    let promises = Object.keys(object).map(key => {
        let getter = getters[key];    // lookup a promise-returning function for the key
        // call it with the param in the object, use the result to fill-in the target object
        return getter(object[key]).then(result => {
            filledInObject[key] = result;
        });
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Call it like this:

```
const getters = { user:getUser, items:getItems }
let opObject = { user: 123456, items: [ 1234, 4321 ] };

fillIn(opObject, getters).then(filledInObject => {
    console.log(filledInObject);
})
```